# New deployment gives nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/postgresql/core/types/PGLong

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat, web-deployment

Every time I deploy my application on apache tomcat server it gives

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/postgresql/core/types/PGLong

I solve this issue by restarting the server along with Postgres but that is not the right solution

Comment: Could you tell us a little more? How do you deploy your project? Is it in WAR? Where is postgres library stored? Does your project use Maven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your version of postgresql make sure it is   9.1-901.jdbc4  change the version in your pom.xml if you using maven  else check the bit of your server along with the installed postgresql version

Answer (score 0):

I go the same type of error when i deploy new war on apache tomcat server

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/postgresql/core/types/PGLong

To solve it I restart the postgresql, then the error solve and project run properly.